# Spring WEB/MVC response writer using HTTPMessageConverter

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring-security:3.2.5.RELEASE and spring-webmvc:4.1.3.RELEASE.
I need to return additional information on log in failure(adding the reason, for example, user is locked, wrong credentials, etc).
I thought to use the `AuthenticationFailureHandler` and write the additional information into the response by hand:

```
@Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("Returning UNAUTHORIZED HttpStatus: " + exception.getMessage());
        try (PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();){
            writer.write(jsonUtils.toJson(new ErrorDTO<String>(HttpStatus.MULTI_STATUS, 234546, exception.getMessage())));
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                    "Authentication Failed: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that since I'm not going throw the Spring's messages converters mechanism, this solution breaks the support in multiple content types (for example, xml, JSON, etc).

Is there a way I can write to the response body by using the messages converter mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a controller that would handle auth failures and then in your `AuthenticationFailureHandler` forward the request to your auth failure controller. In the controller you would have easy access to Spring's message converter mechanisms.

In order to forward the request, take look at the code snippet below (taken from Spring's `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`, `defaultFailureUrl` is the forward destination, which would be path to your auth error handling controller):

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(defaultFailureUrl).forward(request, response);
```